# MIDI 14bit to 7bit conversion pitch bending

Tags: java, midi

I was wondering how do i convert the 14 bit midi pitch bend values

so basically if i have the 14 bit value 8192 (no bend)

how do i express that in the MIDI 0-127 in both the LSB and MSB

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The high 7 bits are the msb and the low 7 bits are the lsb (this is C syntax but I think Java is the same, right?):

```
msb = pitchValue >> 7 & 0x7F;
lsb = pitchValue & 0x7F;
```

So for your value 8192 (0x2000), the msb is 0x40 and the lsb is 0x00.